# Get Predicate used to split values in matlab ClassificationTree

Tags: matlab, classification, decision-tree

I'm using the next code to train a ClassificationTree with one node (Decision stump), using the CutPoint property i was able to get the value of the predicate split, but how can i get the predicate used ? (in this example feature1 or feature2)

```
x1 = 10 * rand(10, 1);
x2 = 10 * rand(10, 1);

x = [x1 x2];
y = randi(2, 10, 1);

t = ClassificationTree.fit(x, y, 'MinParent', 10, 'MergeLeaves', 'off');

view(t)

t.CutPoint(1,:)
```

Output

```
Decision tree for classification
1  if x1<3.60576 then node 2 elseif x1>=3.60576 then node 3 else 1
2  class = 1
3  class = 2


ans =

    3.6058
```

so i was able to get the value 3.6058 but i need a way to get that x1 was the feature used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
t.CutVar{1}

ans =
x1
```

Comment: @Tala, I'm not sure why you think that this does not answer the question - it absolutely does. The questioner asked for a way to obtain the predicate used at a specified CutPoint in the tree, and this is the way to do that. I don't wish to critique or request clarification from the questioner.

Comment: Sorry, Sam, my fault.

Comment: yes, this exactly what i wanted, although i have read the documentation several times, but i didn't notice that one ... thanks